# GDAL works at command line but fails to import to Python

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo, windows-10

I am trying to get GDAL available via Python.  The [PyPI site for for GDAL](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) states that I need to first download and install GDAL.   [Per the instructions at PyPI I have downloaded and installed GDAL from here](https://www.gisinternals.com/).
My methodology was to:

1. Install the required Microsoft Visual C++ components
   [image]
2. Download and install the core GDAL components:

   MSVC 2017 gdal-303-1916-x64-core.msi.
3. Download and install Python bindings:

   MSVC 2017 gdal-3.3.1.win-amd64-py3.7.msi.
4. Set Environment paths to GDAL as shown below.
   [image]

I have a working version of GDAL at the Windows 10 command line.

From pip I can then install GDAL but I get the error message below.  I can open a Python command prompt (or use my Python IDE Wing Pro) but I see no osgeo library, no gdal, library or no ogr2ogr available.

How do I get my Windows 10 computer configured to run GDAL Python?

```
    PS C:\Users\gbg11> pip install GDAL
Collecting GDAL
Using cached GDAL-3.3.1.tar.gz (746 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for GDAL, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Running setup.py install for GDAL ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gbg11\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-81buoujh\\GDAL\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gbg11\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-81buoujh\\GDAL\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ow_oo6cb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Include\GDAL'
        cwd: C:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-81buoujh\GDAL\
         Complete output (139 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
copying osgeo\gnm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
copying osgeo\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
copying osgeo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal2tiles.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal2xyz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalattachpct.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalmove.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_calc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_edit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_fillnodata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_pansharpen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_proximity.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_retile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_sieve.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\ogrmerge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\pct2rgb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\rgb2pct.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\array_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\batch_creator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\color_palette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\color_table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\extent_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\gdal_argparse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\numpy_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\osr_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\progress.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\raster_creation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\rectangle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\assemblepoly.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\build_jp2_from_xml.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\classify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\crs2crs2grid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\densify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\dump_jp2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\epsg_tr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\esri2wkt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\fft.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\fix_gpkg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2vec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2wld.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal2grd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalchksum.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalcopyproj.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalfilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalident.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalimport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdallocationinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_auth.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_cp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_create_pdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_ls.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_lut.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_mkdir.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_remove_towgs84.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_rm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_rmdir.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_vrtmerge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_zip.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\get_soundg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\histrep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\hsv_merge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\jpeg_in_tiff_extract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\load2odbc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\loslas2ntv2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\magphase.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\make_fuzzer_friendly_archive.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\mkgraticule.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr2ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr2vrt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogrinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogrupdate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_build_junction_table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_dispatch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_layer_algebra.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\rel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tigerpoly.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tile_extent_from_raster.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tolatlong.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_cloud_optimized_geotiff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_gpkg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_jp2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\val_repl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\vec_tr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\vec_tr_spat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\wcs_virtds_params.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo_utils\samples
running build_ext
building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
building 'osgeo._gdalconst' extension
building 'osgeo._osr' extension
building 'osgeo._ogr' extension
building 'osgeo._gnm' extension
building 'osgeo._gdal_array' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\extensions
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" -IC:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/osr_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\extensions/osr_wrap.obj
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" -IC:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/gnm_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\extensions/gnm_wrap.obj
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" -IC:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcextensions/gdalconst_wrap.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\extensions/gdalconst_wrap.obj
gdalconst_wrap.c
osr_wrap.cpp
gnm_wrap.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" -IC:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/gdal_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\extensions/gdal_wrap.obj
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" -IC:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/ogr_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\extensions/ogr_wrap.obj
gdal_wrap.cpp
ogr_wrap.cpp
extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c(3018): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdal.h': No such file or directory
extensions/ogr_wrap.cpp(3153): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdal.h': No such file or directory
extensions/osr_wrap.cpp(3198): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_string.h': No such file or directory
extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp(3135): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdal.h': No such file or directory
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(3191): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" -IC:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/gdal_array_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\extensions/gdal_array_wrap.obj
gdal_array_wrap.cpp
extensions/gdal_array_wrap.cpp(3144): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdal.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gbg11\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-81buoujh\\GDAL\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gbg11\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-81buoujh\\GDAL\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ow_oo6cb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\gbg11\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Include\GDAL' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I would highly recommend installing gdal using Anaconda (e.g. `conda install gdal`).

Comment: @Aaron - installing minicoda 3.7 and trying the import in Wing returned the same errors in Wing.  Also, as a result, at the command line gdalinfo --version returns 'can't load  requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_FOO.dll errors' before returning the GDAL 3.1.4 version

Comment: Can you edit your question and specify *exactly* which GISInternals packages you installed. e.g "Stable Releases, GDAL 3.3.1, MSVC 2017, etc...).  Note that Python 3.7 is comiled using MS Visual Studio 2017, so you should use the "MSVC 2017" not "MSVC 2019" GISInternal package.

Comment: @user2856.  I have done a complete unistall and removal of anything GDAL or OSGEO4W.  I have updated my post to detail my methods and the files I used.  My problems have changed a bit in that I cannot import any GDAL related libraries at the command line nor my IDE.

Comment: Are you running both the IDE and GDAL in the same conda environment? Did you reinstall Wing in the GDAL conda environment.

Comment: @Aaron - I purged conda from the computer.  I removed the GDAL conda installation before removing the microconda application.  Similarly, I purged the pip GDAL installation.  I also remove the GDAL core and Python bindings before proceeding with the installation detailed above.  I did not reinstall Wing at any point in this process